# How can I call a plugin function for my wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I put these lines of code in my functions.php

```
if(function_exist("showMessage")){
    showMessage();
}
```

but it gives me a fatal error:

```
"Call to undefined function showMessage"
```

I have this function on my plugin

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like one of two things: 1 - The function hasn't yet been defined (ie. plugin not loaded yet) or 2 - it doesn't get included. Is this code in functions within any other functions or hooks at all?

Comment: plugin already activated. Do I need to add this function on register_Activation_hook? thanks

Comment: The problem would be that the plugin hasn't yet defined the function for the current request. `register_activation_hook` runs when the plugin is activated (when you click that 'Activate' link), so in theory anything hooked to that won't run in a standard request.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `function_exists` instead of `function_exist` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these lines of code above all of my functions in my plugin file and it works like a charm

```
if (!defined('WP_CONTENT_URL'))
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content');
if (!defined('WP_CONTENT_DIR'))
    define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content');
if (!defined('WP_PLUGIN_URL') )
    define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', WP_CONTENT_URL. '/plugins');
if (!defined('WP_PLUGIN_DIR') )
    define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking that function up to the appropriate hook. If you're using this for debug purposes, the earliest time it should run should be in the `init` hook.

Add this to functions file, and it will run the showMessage function when the init hook executes:

```
add_action('init', 'showMessage');
```

For more flexibility, you can change this to use a function that you define:

```
add_action('init', 'run_debug');

function run_debug( ) {
    showMessage();
}
```

For more info, head to http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference.

Comment: Thanks! But my goal is to call the this function on my theme. <?php showMessage(); ?>